# IlGenerator emits leave after throw

Tags: c#, cil, ilgenerator

I'm generating a method by ilgenerator and I have a problem. `IlGenerator.BeginCatchBlock()` forces leave and it is unreachable instruction in this case.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading;
namespace Stack
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var asmName = new AssemblyName("Test");
        var domain = Thread.GetDomain();
        var assembly = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule", "Test.dll", true);
        var type = module.DefineType("MyType");
        var method = type.DefineMethod("MyMethod", MethodAttributes.Public);
        var ilg = method.GetILGenerator();
        ilg.BeginExceptionBlock();
        ilg.ThrowException(typeof(Exception));
        ilg.BeginCatchBlock(typeof(Exception));
        ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        ilg.EndExceptionBlock();
        ilg.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        type.CreateType();
        assembly.Save("test.dll");
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, output is like

```
 .method public instance void MyMethod () cil managed 
    {
            .maxstack 1
            .try
        {
            IL_0000: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Exception::.ctor()
            IL_0005: throw
            IL_0006: leave IL_0011
        } // end .try
        catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
        {
            IL_000b: pop
            IL_000c: leave IL_0011
        } // end handler
        IL_0011: ret
   }
```

I expected to not have leave IL_0011 at .try block. PEVerify shows no errors.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is this a problem? I get that `IL_0006: leave IL_0011` is unreachable, but it seems harmless enough?

Comment: Have a look at the reference source. The `ILGenerator` functions that are related to error handling emitting a few opcodes by themselves and there is nothing do can do about it.

Comment: Reliably detecting unreachable code reduces to the halting problem. In this case, any decent compiler could see the instruction is unreachable, but `Reflection.Emit` is not a compiler, and so it simply always emits a `leave` at the end of the block without trying harder, or giving you the option of omitting it because you know better. For the same reason, PEVerify doesn't complain because unreachable IL code is not an error, it's just redundant. You'll find this kind of "suboptimal" IL is actually common because it's easier, and the JIT compiler is supposed to pick up the slack.

Comment: You told a story: you have a problem, you wrote some code, it did something you didn't expect.  That's a perfectly good story but there is no question here that we can answer. What's your question? If your implied question is "what should I do about it?" then my advice is: when your expectations are contradicted, learn to accept that your expectations were wrong, and adjust them to match reality.  If that's not your question, then *actually ask a question*.